# how to find the common word from given input in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Here i am getting stuck on this. Here is my problem:-
I have one table Service

```
Service table
id     searchservice
1        waxing
2        Waxing
3        American Service
4        Waxing
```

Now i have one input is:-

```
 $searchKeyword = Indian waxing
```

Now i want to find all the records having waxing text i.e. i want to fetch the ids 1,2,4

```
enter code here
Service::Where('searchservice','like','%'.$searchKeyword.'%')->get();
```

It gives me empty result. I know in this i have to use some another sql function. Can anyone help me thanks in advance :) . I am using laravel 5.2 framework

Comment: You current query will search like this `select * from service where searchservice like %Indian waxing%`. Please clarify you want to search only waxing or with each word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for "Indian waxing" if you want to search for each word individually you would have to do:

```
$searchKeyword = "Indian waxing"
$keywords = explode(" ", $searchKeyword);

$service = Service::query();
foreach($keywords as $word){
    $service->orWhere('searchservice', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%');
}

$services = $service->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: `$pages->orWhere`, you meant `$service->orWhere`